# Mobile specific DOM elements?

Tags: html, mobile

Is there a standard way to introduce DOM elements only for mobile, or only for desktop?

For example given the following HTML, it would be nice to have some elements children not render at all into the DOM. This would also play very well with angular-like JS frameworks which make components out of DOM elements. By not existing in the first place for certain browsers, we can prevent execution of entire JS components as well as all of its contents.

```
<div class="mobile-content">

</div>
<div class="desktop-content">
    <!-- expensive desktop-specific DOM elements -->
</div>
```

Responsive CSS isn't the answer, because for example a media query hiding elements via `display: none` will not prevent images within that element from downloading.

One method I've come up with is using `<template>` or `<script type="text/template">` type tags that are injected into the DOM on mobile devices, with the aim of doing this injection as soon as possible on load.

```
<template data-mobile-only>
    <div class="mobile-content" web-components>
    </div>
</template>
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Since you mention Angular, you can have them as partial views.

Comment: @PM77-1, I was inspired by angular and started using other lighter weight web component style frameworks. It's fantastically appropriate to have dom elements directly integrated with well scoped JS.